# Stacked text butted up to logo in web page banner

Tags: html, css, css-float

The idea is to have:
(1) An outer box that sizes to fit the contents.
(2) A logo that floats left.
(3) Two lines of text that stack on top of each other butted up to the right side of the logo.
(4) The box for the top line of text will take up 30% of the vertical space defined by the logo, and the lower line, 70%.

Could anyone help with this?

http://jsfiddle.net/tAVP4/1/

*******    HTML    ******************

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="http://openiconlibrary.sourceforge.net/gallery2/open_icon_library-full/icons/png/48x48/symbols/pictogram-ghs-exclam.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="lines">
        <div id="line1">This is line one</div>
        <div id="line2">This is line two</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

******    CSS    ************

```
#outer {
    border: 3px double black;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    border: 1px dashed green;
}
#logo img {
}
#lines {
    display: inline;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
#line1 {
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 30%;
}
#line2 {
    display: block;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes in the floating and height css attributes.
The main two things I've added are:

```
#outer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#lines {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This is the result:
http://jsfiddle.net/tAVP4/8/

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I wanted -- it even scales.  Any chance you could explain why that  works and mine didn't?  I feel like I took the simplest most intuitive approach.

Comment: Sadly, sometimes the most intuitive approach just doesn't work :)
In order to give child elements (#line1-2) a height attribute with percentage (30%, 70%), the height of their parent element (#lines) must be defined as well.

You were missing this part, so there was nothing saying the #lines element will strech inside the #outer.
What I did is to strech it inside #outer with 'top' and 'bottom' attributes. To do so I had to make #lines' position absolute and its container's position relative.

If my answer helped you, please mark it with the 'V' sign :)

Comment: Thanks much for the explanation.  The height thing definitely makes sense.  I'm still a bit confused about using relative and absolute in general -- a similar thing come up when overlaying images.  Just something I need to play around with more.

Comment: You can search for "css positioning" to learn more. You can also use [this guide](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) and [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fposition)

Comment: I just posted a follow-up question, if you have time...

"background-image-showing-through-picture-with-transparent-background"